# Poor .NET 4 concurrency performance when using dictionary

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, data-structures, concurrency

I am trying to store some data with string keys into a dictionary.
The data is very big e.g. tens of millions of strings.
Therefore, I decided to develop a concurrent version in order to achieve faster execution.
However the concurrent versions' performance is very bad.

I have used two strategies:
1- Split the input into two chunks and insert each chunk into two different dictionaries using two concurrent threads.
2- Insert the whole data into a ConcurrentDictionary using a Parallel.ForEach invocation.

But unfortunately, both strategies' performance is not promising.
The first strategy is about **20~30%** better that is not enough because there is no shared data between tasks.
And, the concurrent collection is about **100% slower**!

Now I am wondering that what is the **problem**???????
Does this mean that there is no chance for parallel speedup in this problem???
I 'll appreciate if anybody can help me :)

I have attached a sample code below.
On my dual core AMD Turion system a sample result is (in milliseconds):
*Initialization: 542

Serial: 294

Parallel: 234

Concurrent Dic: 666*

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        Random r = new Random();
        int count=1000000;
        string[] list = new string[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            list[i] = r.Next(10000).ToString();
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Initialization: "+watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();

        Dictionary<string, byte> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, byte>();
        Dictionary<string, byte> dic2 = new Dictionary<string, byte>();
        foreach (var s in list)
            dic1[s] = 0;

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Serial: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();


        dic1.Clear();

        Task t1 = new Task(
            () =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Length / 2; i++)
                    dic1[list[i]] = 1;
            }
            );
        Task t2 = new Task(
            () =>
            {
                for (int i = list.Length / 2; i < list.Length; i++)
                    dic2[list[i]] = 1;
            }
            );

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Parallel: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();

        ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte> dicp = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte>();
        Parallel.ForEach(list, s =>
            {
                dicp.AddOrUpdate(s, 1, (k, v) => v);
            }
        );

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Concurrent Dic: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();

        return;

    }
```

Comment: so is insert speed really what ur looking for? It might be that the concurrect dictionary is optimized for lookups

Comment: Yes, doesn't work.  Threads buy you cpu cycles if you have enough cores.  You still have only one memory bus.  Compute to take advantage of cpu cycles.  You are not computing, just using memory.  One bus.

Comment: Then, what is the solution???

Comment: I think the Phoenix's wordcount example does a similar task. you can check it at http://mapreduce.stanford.edu/. However, it achieves a good speedup! I know that they also use some mechanisms like hashing. However, they have coded in C language and used PThreads.

Answer (score 2):

`ConcurrentDictionary` being slow is easy to explain: Accessing any entry requires a lock. It is not made for heavy load.

It is much harder to explain why the first `Task`-based benchmark did not see significant speedup. It should have. You correctly partitioned the work with almost no synchronization at all.

Maybe tasks have a one-time startup cost of about 100ms? Try repeating the benchmark 10 times in a loop. Are the results the same for the last run?

Try to create new dictionaries. Reusing an old one carries over state from the old test: A pre-sized internal array.

HansPassant mentions in the comments that you might be memory-bandwidth bound. I don't think this is the case. Dictionary does some not-so-cheap computations internally and modern systems aren't that much bandwidth-bound. They might be latency-bound but not bandwidth.

Comment: I think U have got the problem! I have run the program several times. some times the performance of the two-threaded solution is acceptable. In my dual core system, sometime it achieves near double speedup but it seldom occurs. Usually the performance is as I mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

There are few optimizations you can come up with.
1. Because you've mentioned there is really huge amount of data, try to specify an initial size for the dictionry to a big number (approximately the amount you're expecting to store in it)
2. Try to avoid multithreading in this case - I see no benefit here, if its all about inserting.

Comment: Good advice, but not answering the *why*-part which is what is asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not designed to do hold epic amounts of entries like yours seems to (tens of millions). In fact there is an [attack on ASP.NET](https://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/david/archive/2012/01/20/hashdos-ndash-the-post-of-doom-explained.aspx) which relies exactly on the fact that asp.net dictionaries start having hash collisions pretty early.

This means that the has has to rely on it's collision avoidance mechanism which usually isn't O(1) but O(n) (n being the number of keys that have collided). This can slow a dictionary down quite a bit, as demonstrated by the attack.

Couple hash collisions with the locking mechanisms and you have a significant slowdown.

Also, keep in mind that parallel tasks are meant for routines that take a while and don't share a lot of data between each other, like processing photos. Adding entries in a dictionary is super fast even with collisions, and the locking and palatalization features are significantly slower. This coupled with the fact that you have a single dictionary that needs to be created (which is a bottleneck in parallel processing) and you have an explanation of why it takes longer with parallel to initialize your dictionary.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hash collisions arise because of *malicious* input. Dictionary *is* designed to hold millions of keys.

Comment: I know, that's why it has a hash collision mitigation strategy implemented. The article I mentioned did talk about malicious input but collisions do happen in normal use cases as well, and the frequency tends to go up the more entries there are in the dictionary.

Comment: The frequency doesn't go up because the dictionary resizes itself. Hashtables are suitable for arbitrary amounts of data. Collisions don't become worse.

Comment: @linkerro Sorry for that but I think you have not answered my question at all!

Comment: @usr the collision happens when two keys have the same hash. Dictionary resizing has no bearing on the collisions since it doesn't change the hashing function. The larger the key collection, the higher the chance of a collision.

Comment: @SaeedShahrivari tl;dr version: you can't use parallel tasks for entering data into dictionaries because the locking mechanisms slow you down.

Comment: The larger the collection the more possible keys. index = hashResult % arraySize. Hashtables having O(1) is a well-known result which holds in practice.

Comment: @usr dude, you are so right. I completely forgot that the collision chance is linked to the array fill rate not the array size.

Comment: @linkerro if U look at my first strategy, U can see that I am inserting into two different dictionaries! There is no locking, no mutual state and totally different operations!!!! Then how can U explain this???

Answer (score 0):

1) Been said. Give the dictionary constructor an initial size. This forces the structure to allocate at least this many entries/buckets.

2) See if you can use shorter strings if this is possible.

3) Internally the Dictionary will be doing many string comparisons no doubt. Pass your own string comparer to the Dictionary constructor.

```
new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Comment: Why would a dictionary compare strings?

Comment: Key values are compared within a Dictionary afaik. So if the key's are strings, then they will be compared. Ordinal string comparisons are fast. Dictionary uses a default IEqualityComparer<T> implementation if one such as Ordinal is not provided. This interface requires both an Equals an GetHashCode method to be implemented. The equals will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You've suggested 3 solutions for your problem which are Serial, Parallel and `ConcurrentDictionary`.

First of all, your 2nd solution (the parallel one) is a solution for a totally different question than 1st and 3rd. It's result is not a single dictionary, while the other 2 solutions results a single dictionary. The reason that it seems the parallel one is better at performance is that it doesn't finish yet. You have one step more to merge `dic1` and `dic2`.

Anyway if you would like your parallel solution to add in a same dictionary, you have to put a `lock` to avoid race condition. Putting a lock for adding makes your parallel solution just like the 3rd solution (As ConcurrentDictionary may have better implementation of using locks, the 3rd might be a little faster).

BTW, when you have a list (or a dictionary) to fill, and all of you input data is ready, the bottleneck part algorithm is just the `Add` cost. Even if you use multiple threads to do adding because of using the `lock`, each thread should wait for others to finish their adding job. So practically you will have lots of threads (tasks) waiting for each other, making your solution running like a sequential one plus the overhead of context switching.

At the end, parallel programming won't help you for this situation at all. To optimize your algorithm you should make the adding part more optimized. For example you could have an initial size for your dictionary (helping the add method not to run list extension part).
Or you could define a faster Comparer (In your situation which the strings are too large).
Personally, I think designing an optimized comparer would affect a lot on performance in the situation. You may use some hashing in your comparer algorithm.